# Sitecore Bright Cove Module:Image Preview type get erased on editing BrightcoveVideo

Tags: image, sitecore, preview, brightcove, sitecore7.1

I am using BrightCove Module in Sitecore. Details are as below:

1. Sitecore Version:

   Sitecore 7.1 rev. 130926.exe
2. BrightCove Packages Installed:

   Sitecore Media Framework 1.2 rev. 131220.zip

   Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove Edition 1.2 rev. 131220.zip

Here after importing the media item,when i try to edit a bright cove video,Fields of type **Image Preview**(EX:**Thumbnail URL,Video Still URL**) get vanished.Please find screen shots below:

After Importing the Media Items from brightcove:
[image]

Now I edit Name field and save:
[image]

Any Idea on the issue?

Thanks,
Suhas

Comment: You should contact Sitecore Support since they support this framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the same bug. 
But these fields will be updated if you click Import again or if you use scheduler for the Import and Cleanup.
Don't panic if you click Import and may not see result right now, Media Framework uses queue,  after a while it will be updated.

In any case that is a bug. Would be great if you contact to Sitecore Support.

Comment: That was a bug and I got the fix from sitecore.Thanks